# Laravel & Localization: How to handle same language in different countries?

Tags: php, laravel, localization

Although Laravel calls it "localization" i do not see a solution to create different language-files for e.g. en_EN and en_US.

In all tutorials i only find e.g. "/resources/lang/en/.php" - for a real localization i'd expect "/resources/lang/en_EN/.php" and "/resources/lang/en_US/.php" instead.

Is there a solution to get it working without writing a own solution?

Regards, Rafael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really simple all you have to do is to create a new folder in your "resources/lang" for example you want to make British English and American English then you can do the following

lets create two translation files called main.php one for American and one for British

```
"/resources/lang/en_us/main.php"
"resources/lang/en_uk/main.php"
```

now as normal for English the locale was en right here the locale would be `en_us` and `en_uk` respectively , all locale does that it tells Laravel which folder inside lang directory to read from that's all if you don't know how to make a localization middleware I suggest you read [This Artice](http://www.mundointerativo.com/2017/10/12/laravel-5-5-localization-scratch/)

Hope this help you, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the fallback locale (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/localization) in a ServiceProvider depending on the current locale. So if the locale is en_US, set the fallback to en_En so it uses that file instead for missing keys. This way you could for example use color -> colour or elevator -> lift.

In **lang/en_GB.php**

```
config(['app.fallback_locale' => 'en_US']); // set fallback

// continue rest of translation
return [
    'elevator ' => 'lift',
];
```